# sed with complex string

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to sed into phpMyAdmin config file to add a blowfish key.

Here's what I have so far...

```
k=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
o="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';"
n="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$k';" 
sed -i -e 's/'"$o"'/'"$n"'/g' /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

I don't get any error, but it's not working as expected.

```
echo -e "$k\n$o\n$n"
```

returns

```
Jgcv3FlugcVi5rDYLCdNhxX6sEZatt0zTZV3PISiLJY=
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'Jgcv3FlugcVi5rDYLCdNhxX6sEZatt0zTZV3PISiLJY=';
```

And...

```
cat /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php | grep blowfish
```

returns

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

Please help!

Comment: `[]` are character classes and are being interpreted as such by sed. It would be better to use awk or perl and do exact matches instead of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS 123 mentioned in a comment [] characters were interpreted as character classes by sed, simply escaping it with backslash solved my problem.

So this :

```
k=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
o="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';"
n="\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$k';" 
sed -i -e 's/'"$o"'/'"$n"'/g' /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Was changed to that :

```
k=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
o="\$cfg\['blowfish_secret'\] = '';"
n="\$cfg\['blowfish_secret'\] = '$k';" 
sed -i -e 's/'"$o"'/'"$n"'/g' /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

And now it works.

EDIT :

Since ***openssl rand -base64 32*** can generate a string with slashes, it's better to escape it right away. Also, I chose to use perl after all. Here's the corrected code:

```
k=$(openssl rand -base64 32 | sed 's,\/,\\/,g')
o="\$cfg\['blowfish_secret'\] = '';"
n="\$cfg\['blowfish_secret'\] = '$k';"
sudo perl -p -i -e "s/$o/$n/g" /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Comment: If you want to simplify the `sed` command a bit, you could use a single double quoted string, since the only meta-characters that the shell will interpret are the variable expansions: `sed -i -e "s/$o/$n/g"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all kind of special regex meta characters in search and replace strings here is a non-regex way of doing that using `awk`:

```
# utility function to format search and replace strings
frmt() {
   printf "\$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '%s';" "$1"
}

# awk command to perform search and replace using plain text search
awk -v s="$(frmt "")" -v r="$(frmt "$k")" 'n=index($0, s) {
   print r substr($0, n+length(s))
}' /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

PS: Note that above `awk` command doesn't do inline editing of the file. If you want to do that then use `-i inline` option available with `gnu-awk` as:

```
awk -i inline -v s="$(frmt "")" -v r="$(frmt "$k")" 'n=index($0, s) {
   print r substr($0, n+length(s))
}' /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Comment: Think inline is only available gawk 4.0+